# Customize Wordpress Theme Lightbox

Tags: jquery, wordpress, lightbox, colorbox

I have downloaded this theme: http://themeforest.net/item/havva-portfolio-for-freelancers-agencies/full_screen_preview/10666379

If you click on one of the pictures, there opens a new page with the picture and a description. If you click one more time on the picture, there will open a lightbox with the picture in it.

Now, I have no descriptions for my pictures, so I think that I don't need a new page to open. What I want is, to open the images in that lightbox when I click on them in the portfolio gallery view (on the front page). I don't want the new page between looking at the thumbnail and having the lightbox open.

What I tried to do so far:

This is the code of the main page/front page to open a new page with the image:

```
                        <div class="front">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
                                    <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, array(300,$height) ); ?>
                                <?php }else{ ?>
                                    <img src="<?php echo esc_url(WF_IMAGES.'no-thumb.png'); ?>" />
                                <?php } ?>
                            </a>
                        </div>
```

This is the Code of the new page to open the lightbox with the image:

```
<div class="featured-portfolio"><?php echo $media; ?></div>
```

I thought I could just implement the Code of the new page to the front page, but I don't know what is in that $media variable or how to get to its content to get to the lightbox link...

Could you maybe help me here?

Greetings,
Linda

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the frontend code for the image that does open in a lightbox, Ex:

```
<a class="colorbox-url cboxElement" rel="gallery_119" href="...">
    <img width="750" height="746" src="..." class="attachment-full-width" alt="ab" data-wp-pid="268">
</a>
```

It looks like the element class is being used to indicate the the link should be opened in a lightbox.

A quick search on the JS reveals:

```
$('.colorbox-url').live('click', function(){
    $.colorbox({href:$(this).attr('href'), open:true, maxWidth:'80%', maxHeight:'80%', fixed:true});
    return false;
});
```

You can try adding the class to your link on the index page:

```
<div class="front">
    <a href="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'large'); ?>" class="colorbox-url cboxElement">
        ...
    </a>
</div>
```

Notice I also changed the `href` attribute to the image rather than the single post page. I just set the size to `large`, you may want a different image size.

It's hard to say whether or not that is sufficient to trigger the lightbox, the lightbox itself may require some initialization, but it should at least set you on the right path.

Comment: Hmm... When I add the class like you did, it just looks like this: I had that problem several times in other pages. The code just doesn't get that far to really add the class to the link. I copied and pasted the line:
<a href="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'large' ); ?>" class="colorbox-url cboxElement">
instead of this:
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
[link](http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3987/cjb6269a_png.htm)

Comment: Can you clarify "doesn't get that far"? Is there an error in your code before the link?

Comment: Yeah, when you look in the link in my first comment you can see in the screenshot that this Code:
" class="colorbox-link cboxElement">

Shows up above each item of the front Page in the browser

Comment: You can't post screenshots in comments. All I see is `it just looks like this: I had...`

Comment: Do you get it when I just paste the link? http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3987/cjb6269a_png.htm

Comment: It looks like there is an error in your HTML somewhere. Maybe an missing quote that is preventing the anchor from rendering correctly.

Comment: Yeah I thought that, too. But I don't get the mistake. I took that code line from you like you wrote it here. But I had a really similar situation some weeks ago with some php code in html... Could it maybe an editor error or something I have to configure in the editor?

Comment: I have no idea. I noticed there is a syntax highlighting issue in the question and my response (I copied the code from your question). There might be an encoding issue somewhere. I would try retyping the code by hand.

Comment: Hi! I retyped the code by hand now and now it seems to trigger the lightbox. But if I click on one of the items, it's just loading all the time (a loading graphic is spinning around)... What can this be? Look at the Screenshot: directupload.net/file/d/3988/6blj396v_png.htm

In the front-page code I can see, that the anchor "href" is empty. It doesn't get the element url...

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the "echo"... Now it is working! But just for the preloaded items. If you scroll down the page, there are more items loaded and they don't get the classes "colorbox-url" and "cboxElement"... Why is that like this? Do you know where I could search for the problem?